# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: 14.04, wireless, atheros, ubuntu-gnome

I'm new in Ubuntu and just downloaded Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS.
The PC is working fine. The problem is that the internet is kinda slow.
It loads the pages but it takes forever. Seen an HD quality video on YouTube is impossible.
I've tried what it says here: 
http://pkill-9.com/stabilizing-atheros-ar9485-ath9k-connection-linux-wheezy/
However, where it says to write

```
cd /etc/network # go to network interfaces
sudo cp interfaces interfaces.org # make a backup copy
sudo nano interfaces
```

I get:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And in 'HOKEY POKEY PART 2!' my PC shows the same message as in the step 5.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem I would really appreciate.

After using iwlist scan, this is what it shows:

```
 Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1 Group Cipher : TKIP Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

PS: I have dual-boot with windows 8 x64 and the internet works perfectly.

Comment: I have a AR9485 wifi chip and it works fine in Ubuntu, you might want to check your wifi router settings to make sure they are WPA2-AES or WPA2-PSK only, check with `iwlist scan` in terminal to check your wifi settings, you want to see WPA2 Version 1 and CCMP, absolutely no TKIP

Comment: It shows nothing?  Here is part of what the same command shows on my laptop ` IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
`

Comment: Change the router settings and see if you can't eliminate TKIP

Comment: Will try, but how can you explain that on Windows it works fine?

Comment: @Zatzfara Windows uses a different driver.

Comment: @Zatzfara Can you try changing the router from WPA/WPA2 mixed to straight WPA2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the wifi router so that the `iwlist scan` shows only CCMP and no TKIP and the following command might help `echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` and reboot

Comment: The settings of my router shows under security mode: 'WPA/WAP2 mixed personal' which is the equivalent to AES+TKIP (I have a Linksys E4200). So I believe is not a router problem. The PC should be able to connect as CCMP.

Comment: Actually now it works perfectly as I disabled the guest network on my router.
However, with the guest network, it works when I changed to WPA2 personal.

Answer (score 1):

Mixed mode is a bad plan. Many devices do not like the idea. You may get away with it with Windows 7 because "you can configure a profile using various methods (wpa-aes, wpa-tkip)" but "many devices don't like when you have both WPA-TKIP and WPA2-AES configured in a WLAN"

Source: Scott Fella on [this page.](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11537196/wpa-and-wpa2-both-using-tkip-and-aes) Since it appears he's a Cisco Tech and Cisco purchased Linksys a while back I know I believe him.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Gnome are you running? Gnome 3 is known to be a resource hog. Try Ubuntu in either Unity or KDE.